# Meaning of bolded line

Tags: word-usage

**All the snacks she once scolded him for**. Was she cruel to feel more happiness, greater relief, at his return, than for her daughter on the day he had come back for? Before Rafiq left to oversee arrangements in the hall—the tables brought in, golden bows tied to the chairs, the setting of the stage where Hadia and Tariq would sit—Layla climbed the stairs to their bedroom, where he was getting ready.

Comment: It's unclear what the context is. Perhaps it means that all the snacks that she used to scold him for eating, would be served.

Comment: The context needed is what **precedes** the line in bold type. That line is not a complete sentences; it lacks a verb. Consequently, it is grammatically meaningless. Presumably the preceding sentences will **imply** a verb that will cure the technical defect.